# What does しやがって imply? shiyagatte doesn't seem to show up directly in dictionaries

Tags: conjugations

I've run across the expression/word a few times in manga, and generally the context indicates that it's a conjugation of する with the ～がる indication of "3rd party appearance of internal state" (as in 怖い -> 怖がる). Is this generally correct? If so, where the や comes from? or is this just yet another 'special' conjugation?

An example fragment I have here is:

> いつも, すました顔しやがって...

(Context is a few moments before a love declaration... meaning is obvious enough)

Another example comes from pg 12 of the first QED manga, where an enraged player who has just lost a video game competition yells:

> こっちの動き全部読んでますってな動きしやがってよ！！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 「する」の連用形＋「やがる」 conjugated into て-form.

Basically やがる does not do much aside from make the sentence rougher. Technically, it express a disdain for the action it attaches to, but personally I think it's not quite so strict on usage. You hear it very often in anime-talk where everyone is trying to sound rough and manly. Generally not in real life unless it's a very tense situation, or the people are close enough for it to not be offensive (like in that first quote of yours).

Here is a question covering やがる in more detail: [How to use the inflection "やがる"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4236/how-to-use-the-inflection-%E3%82%84%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B)