# What does 嵐にしやがれ mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

I recently stumbled accross the japanese tv show [嵐にしやがれ](http://www.ntv.co.jp/arashinishiyagare/) and have been wondering what its title means. 「しやがれ」doesn't appear in any dictionary I use, but I found some rather unreliable online sources saying it translates to something along the lines of 「～しなさい」or 「～しろ」. However, even with that in mind, the title 「嵐にしやがれ」does not make a whole lot of sense to me.

Is there any story behind it? Is it maybe some word-play with the group 「嵐」's name. Something like 'let's make a storm'/'let's go wild'?

Comment: する＋やがる＋imperative

Comment: I will try to find out, but, while not knowing the show (I may have seen it, though, since my wife is also a big fan of them), I would also think it is a word-play, but, maybe not necessarily related to Arashi, could it just be about しあがれ being deformed to しやがれ?

Comment: Partly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4236/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**し** is the pre-masu form (aka stem) of する, and **やがれ** is the imperative form of the auxiliary verb やがる which adds the nuance of "damn" to the main verb. See [What does しやがって imply? shiyagatte doesn't seem to show up directly in dictionaries](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11966/5010) for details. So しやがれ on its own means something like "(darn,) do it!". It's essentially a rougher version of しろ.

And `N + にする`, where N is a noun/na-adjective, means "to choose N", "to make it N", "to go in N way", etc. All in all, 嵐にしやがれ means something along the lines of "Bet on Arashi!", "Go with Arashi, man!". (嵐's literal meaning, *storm*, is not particularly relevant now.)

That being said, as @YuuichiTam said, this title is primarily perceived as a parody of 勝手にしやがれ, and its literal meaning may not be taken seriously.

Answer (score 3):

I think it doesn't have any meaning and just a title parody of 勝手にしやがれ. 勝手にしやがれ is used as a title of a famous movie and songs, etc. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8B%9D%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%82%84%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8C

Comment: It might be worth editing this answer to add a link to an explanation of the auxiliary verb やがる (maybe this one https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4236/how-to-use-the-inflection-やがる), since it looks like the OP is unfamiliar with it.