# what is the exact meaning of "部長が自分のミス俺のせいにしゃがってさ" in below sentence

Tags: には

I don't understand exactly the meaning of  "部長が自分のミス俺のせいにしゃがってさ"
the whole sentence is:  今日もさ 部長が自分のミス俺のせいにしゃがってさ冗談じゃ ないよ お前 部下をかばってこそ 上司だろ おい!

the meaning in the text is: today, the head of my department tried to blame me for his screwup. “This is wrong!” I said. “A chief is a chief because he protects his subordinates!”

but I want to know the grammar points of the aforesaid sentence and if the meaning is correct or not.

Comment: could you give a bit more detail on what you are confused about? Is it the にしやがって that is bothering you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's しゃがる that's troubling you, it's not しゃがる but しやがる, which is し (masu-stem of する) + [やがる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4236/5010).

If it's てさ that's troubling you, see: [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010)

This sentence uses the AをBにする ("to make A B", "to turn A into B", "to pretend A as B") construction, although を has been omitted:

> 部長が自分のミス**を**俺のせいにしやがった。
> The chief turned his own error into my fault.
> → The chief blamed me for his own mistake.